# Is there a way to spawn blocks without using multiple command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering if I can use the `/setblock x y z` command to set blocks using 0 - 1 blocks per command block.

Comment: I am unclear about the meaning of the question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Someone edited my question and made it confusing I was wondering if you can use the /SET BLOCK with just one command block or a smaller amount of command blocks like 5 blocks placed per command block

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a rectanguloid, fill is good. But they all have to be the same block. The syntax `/fill x1 y1  z1 x2 y2 z2 block` where x1 y1 and z1 are the coords of the bottom left corner and x2 y2 and z2 the top right corner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Frank I think this is an attempted answer to the question, just a poor-quality one.

Comment: @colorfusion I'm having trouble seeing how it answers the question *at all*.  There's no attempt to help with a command, or any general advice.

Comment: @Frank They haven't given the syntax or anything, but they have said that fill lets you create cuboids of the same block type.

Comment: He/she asked for a command, I gave him/her a commander

Comment: @colorfusion Okay.  So a command is given.  Without usage guidelines, an example, or anything.  There's *nothing* here to actually help someone.

Comment: @Frank Yeah, it isn't a good answer. Just mean that it *is* an attempt at an answer, rather than a comment, so feedback such as "Give more detail and examples" would be more useful than telling them how to leave a comment to critique the question.

Comment: @colorfusion From what I saw, there was no relation to actually answering the question.  It could *be* a low quality answer, but from the little I saw, it wasn't even that.  Now that there is, yeah, I can see it being an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fill multiple blocks there are a few choices. First if you have a rectangular shaped area, use the fill command: `/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> block`.

Second choice is to use command block mine carts stacked in a single block space each with an individual `/setblock` command in it. This method will cause large amounts of lag if you need to fill a large area.

Thirdly, if you use a one-command-block system you are able to create large structured w/ one command block. This method is however the slowest of all of them but does not have the restrictions of the first method and does not cause the constant lag of the second method. The idea behind it is to summon multiple FallingSand tile entities riding each other so when they land they will create a tower of command blocks that can be activated by one fill command block to run multiple commands from a single command block.